# default value in ng-options with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The question is very simple: ¿How can I set a init value for my ng-options? The problem is that the default value have to be a specific value, for know what is the specific value I need a condition.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption1" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.guardarHorarioInicial($index, selectedOption1)">
```

My JSON is the following

[image]

For each options, I need to check if the value of the option is equals to valorInicio. If the option is equal to the value of valorInicio, I need to choose this value by default

With the old format I used:

```
ng-selected="dia.valorInicio == horario"
```

And works perfect.

But now I don't have ng-selected.

So.. Someone can help me?

Thanks!

**//EDIT//**

**HTML**

```
<ion-view view-title="Cambiar horarios">
<ion-content>
    <div class="list card" ng-repeat="dia in vm.dias">
        <div class="item item-divider" align="center">
            {{dia.nombre}}
        </div> 
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Primer turno
                </div>
                <select ng-model="selectedOption1" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.guardarHorarioInicial($index, selectedOption1)">
                </select>
                <!--<select>
                    <option ng-model="selectedOption1" ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" ng-selected="dia.valorInicio == horario" ng-change="vm.guardarHorarioInicial($index, selectedOption1)" value="{{horario}}">{{horario}}</option>
                </select>-->
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Último turno
                </div><!--
                <select ng-model="selectedOption2" required="required" ng-init="'09:00'=='09:00'" ng-options="horario as horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.guardarHorarioFinal($index, selectedOption2)"    >
                </select>-->
                <select>
                    <option ng-model="selectedOption2" ng-repeat="horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.guardarHorarioFinal($index, selectedOption2)" ng-selected="dia.valorFin == horario" value="{{horario}}">{{horario}}</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding-horizontal"><button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="vm.guardarHorarios()"> Guardar horarios </button></div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Controller**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('example.cambiarhorarios')
    .controller('CambiarHorariosController', CambiarHorariosController);

CambiarHorariosController.$inject = ['$state', '$scope', 'cambiarHorariosService'];

function CambiarHorariosController($state, $scope, cambiarHorariosService ) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.estado = false;
    vm.estadoCambiarHorarios = false;
    vm.dias = [];
    vm.mensajeError = '';
    vm.cargarHorarios = cargarHorarios;
    vm.guardarHorarioInicial = guardarHorarioInicial;
    vm.guardarHorarioFinal = guardarHorarioFinal;
    vm.horariosInicial = [];
    vm.horariosFinal = [];


    inicializar();

    function inicializar() {
        cargarHorarios();

    }

    //guardar todos los horarios del primer turno
    function guardarHorarioInicial(index){
        //horariosInicial[index] = 
        console.log("indexxxxxx:"+index);
        console.log("Option 1 : " + $scope.selectedOption1);
        debugger;
        //vm.horarios[index] = vm.test[index];

    }


    function cargarHorarios() {
        vm.estado = false;
        vm.estadoCambiarHorarios = false;
        cambiarHorariosService.obtenerHorariosComplejo()
            .then(function(dias) {
                vm.dias = dias;
                mostrarCambiarHorarios(true);
            })
            .catch(function(e){
                mostrarCambiarHorarios(false);
                vm.mensajeError = e.concat(" Toca para volver a cargar.");
        });
    }

    //funcion para visualizar los datos o mostrar un error
    function mostrarCambiarHorarios(estado){
        if(estado == true){
            vm.estado = true;
        }
        else{
            vm.estado = false;
            vm.estadoCambiarHorarios = true;
        }
    }

    //guardar todos los horarios del primer turno
    function guardarHorarioInicial(index, hora){
        vm.horariosInicial[index] = hora;
        console.log(vm.horariosInicial);
    }

    //guardar todos los horarios del último turno
    function guardarHorarioFinal(index, hora){
        vm.horariosFinal[index] = hora;
        console.log(vm.horariosFinal);
    }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! I had to set in ng-model the value or (in my case) the property from my json that I want to show by default.

Also, when the user change the option, automatically change the value in my json, because angular gonna change the variable that you set in the model.

```
select ng-model="dia.valorInicio" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.modificarHoraInicio($index, dia.valorInicio)"></select>


<select ng-model="dia.valorFin" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.modificarHoraFin($index, dia.valorFin)"></select>
```

Thanks @AndersVestergaard for helping me trying to resolve my problem that made me found the answer.

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 1):

You set the selectedOption1 to be equal the init selected horario.
You can do this ex in the controller constructor like this pseudo code:

```
if(conditionForInitSelectedObject == horarios[i]){
  $scope.selectedOption1 = horarios[i];        
}
```

**Extra edit as code was shown:**

```
function cargarHorarios() {
    vm.estado = false;
    vm.estadoCambiarHorarios = false;
    cambiarHorariosService.obtenerHorariosComplejo()
        .then(function(dias) {
            vm.dias = dias;

            for(var i = 0; i < dias.horario.length; i++){
               if(dias.horario[i] == dia.valorInicio){
                 $scope.selectedOption1 = dias.horario[i];
               }

               if(dias.horario[i] == dia.valorFin ){
                 $scope.selectedOption2 = dias.horario[i];
               }

            }

            mostrarCambiarHorarios(true);
        })
        .catch(function(e){
            mostrarCambiarHorarios(false);
            vm.mensajeError = e.concat(" Toca para volver a cargar.");
    });
}
```

**Edit 2**

The data structure was not clear to me in my privious edits so the problem is that there are multiple options how do i initial select one in each according to some data.

**Solution 1:**
You could use ng-selected if you use ng-repeat on option tags

**Solution 2:**
You could do as my first answer stated, but edit the html so the ngModel was not saved in some static variables but rather:

```
<select ng-model="dia.Selected" ng-options="horario for horario in dia.horarios" ng-change="vm.guardarHorarioInicial($index, selectedOption1)">
```

And the init when you get data.
This plunker shows the idea:https://plnkr.co/edit/UHasuk0RvYCS8omzlsg4?p=preview

Comment: I don't know how to implement what you said, sorry about that. See my edit answer with the full code, may be you can tell me exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: Sry my foreign language skills (the variable names) is limited but as far as I can see cambiarHorariosService.obtenerHorariosComplejo() is where you get your dias data?

Comment: Yes, obtenerHorariosComplejo return me the json like the image above

Comment: So I would just make a forloop and select the correct value. You can of course optimize the code, but this should be transparent. Beware of syntax errors and spell errors, pls comment if you find any.

Comment: So I see I missunderstod your data structure a bit. So you can have multiple selectedOption1 right?

So dias[0].horarios[x] has a selectedOption1 and
dias[1].horarios[x] has a selectedOption1 then this solution wont work but it's still possible to achieve your goal with small changes

Comment: One more question. Why have you choosen not to use ng-selected anymore? It would be easier :)

Comment: Because not working ng-selected with ng-options, isn't it? II have a multiples selectedOptions. Your answers not working properly because the services return me dias, and dias have 7 child, so we have to loop each child of dia to do dia[i].horarios[j]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131754/discussion-between-federick-jons-and-anders-vestergaard).